# How do we provide two different url's for different users in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, portal

i have developed a portal using Liferay.I have two kind of users, guest user and Admin user. The login should be possible by the Admin only. The guest user should not be able to login , or even see the sign in button. How do i achieve this? through different url's?

Comment: How do you want to distinguish between Administrators and guest users *before* they're logged in? When they're not logged in, they're both guests.

Comment: Yes. That exactly is the problem. That's why I suggested the hidden page solution.

Comment: Understood (and upvoted). But I wanted to explicitly ask this because the answer to this question helps to think about the problem differently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider the following approach:
Remove the login portlet from the theme template. (portal-normal.vm) 
Create a hidden page on your Guest group. On this page you place only the login portlet. So only the people who know the direct URL are able to login. AFAIK there is no other way to achieve this, as you don't know if someone is an Admin before he entered his credentials ;)

[EDIT]
To remove the login portlet from the template you have to do the following steps:
A) If you don't have a custom theme
- Create a new Theme
- Parent of your new theme is classic 
- Place portal_normal.vm in /docroot/_diffs/templates
- Remove these lines:

```
    #if (!$is_signed_in)
        <a data-redirect="$is_login_redirect_required" href="$sign_in_url" id="sign-in" rel="nofollow">$sign_in_text</a>
    #end
```

That should remove the login link.
- Compile and deploy your theme
- Assign the theme to the portal as default theme. Assign the theme to your guest group Site.

Now you only have to create your hidden page and place the login portlet on it. 
[/EDIT]

Comment: Hi, this approach seems fine.. Can you please explain it ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how I can go more into detail, as all you have to do is already written in my Answer. Which part is unclear to you?  Also I really want to point out, that you  removing the View permissions for guest for the login portlet will break your portal, because no one will be able to log in. (Because you are Guest if you are not logged in)

Comment: That is my concern, if no one will be able to log in then how is it possible? And you also mentioned of creating a hidden page. Will that approach work? how to go about with it?

Comment: When you add a page in Liferay, there is an option called "hide in Menu" or something in that ductus. Check it, and the page will not be visible in the menus. Now you can access the page by entering the URL in your browser. http://locahost:8080/group/guest/myHiddenLoginPage for example. On that page you place your Login portlet. No need to adjust any permission.

Comment: ok got it.. What about theme template? and how do i remove login portlet? and place it in this hidden page?

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider an alternative approach if you know sth more about the admin users - e.g. their IP address / addresses, then you could modify the contents of a page in a similar manner as stated by Gevatterjan, but then you check not for the signed-in users, but the ones with specfic IPs.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a very practical approach. IP addresses can change, but the implementation would require you to hardcode assumptions (Admins will have one of these IP's), if you have a new admin, you would have to add his/or her IP's. And we are only talking about the implications when the portal is accessed from the web. What about more complex IT Infrastructures in bigger companies? You will end up with messy code and a lot of work maintaining it.

Comment: That was just an example of assumption and I would say that this one does not pose a problem in implementation and maintenance. There are lots of situations in corporate environments where IPs are known and sometimes tied to a user. Hardcoding would really be messy but who prevents the implementer from using a property file or a database for storing the mappings?